# Refer to id of views dynamically with template strings?

Tags: android, kotlin

(I'm sorry if I didn't use the correct term in the title.)

I have many widgets of ImageView with ids of image1, image2, image3, etc.
I would like to refer to one of them (for example image2) dynamically using an integer, something like:

```
val position = 2
image{position}.x = ....
```

Is such thing possible in Kotlin/Android? I'm only trying this direction since I know it's possible in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getIdentifier to get the identifier of your images like so:

```
int resId = context.resources.getIdentifier(
    "image${position}",
    "drawable",
    context.packageName
);
```

or to get ids of image views like so:

```
int resId = context.resources.getIdentifier(
    "image${position}",
    "id",
    context.packageName
);
```

Once you have the id's you could load drawables or views how you normally would with `findViewById(resId)` or `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId)`

Make sure to call `findViewById()` on the parent of the view you are trying to find.

Comment: Hello Quinn thank you, I did try that but I cannot get the properties of resId as if it were the ImageView widget, maybe I did something wrong with "context"? Since it's Kotlin and not Java I cannot use context, I tried with applicationContext and it didn't work. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advnace

Comment: @sir-haver the code i provided is kotlin, applicationConext works fine. The resId is NOT an ImageView, it is the id of the image view. You will need to use `findViewById(resId)` to get the view itself.

Comment: Oh yeah it's my bad it all makes sense now, thanks a lot!